Postgres planning time is very high
I have a table named, and it has enough CPU, memory, and shared buffers. But when I run a simple query:
Explain analyse SELECT * FROM assets WHERE leased_to = 'org_name' or owned_by = 'org_name' ;

planning takes more than 6 seconds for new session but subsequent sessions takes less less planing time.
For your info leased_to and owned_by are indexed.
Explain analyse SELECT * FROM assets WHERE leased_to = 'org_name' or owned_by = 'org_name';
                                                          QUERY PLAN                                                           
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Bitmap Heap Scan on assets  (cost=5.01..102.52 rows=147 width=2040) (actual time=0.060..0.293 rows=147 loops=1)
   Recheck Cond: ((leased_to = 'org_name'::text) OR (owned_by = 'org_name'::text))
   Heap Blocks: exact=56
   ->  BitmapOr  (cost=5.01..5.01 rows=149 width=0) (actual time=0.044..0.046 rows=0 loops=1)
         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_leased_to  (cost=0.00..1.49 rows=32 width=0) (actual time=0.031..0.031 rows=32 loops=1)
               Index Cond: (leased_to = 'org_name'::text)
         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_owned_by  (cost=0.00..3.45 rows=147 width=0) (actual time=0.012..0.012 rows=149 loops=1)
               Index Cond: (owned_by = 'org_name'::text)
 Planning Time: 8732.087 ms
 Execution Time: 0.380 ms
(10 rows)


max_connections = 200
shared_buffers = 1536MB
wal_buffers = 16MB
work_mem = 4096kB
checkpoint_completion_target = 0.9
effective_io_concurrency = 200
maintenance_work_mem = 128MB
effective_cache_size = 1023MB
random_page_cost = 1.1
wal_level = logical
max_replication_slots = 15

Version: postgresql:14.4.0-debian-11-r9
SELECT schemaname, relname, n_dead_tup FROM pg_catalog.pg_stat_all_tables ;
     schemaname     |           relname           | n_dead_tup 
--------------------+-----------------------------+------------
 pg_catalog         | pg_statistic                |    1567454
 pg_toast           | pg_toast_2619               |     429588
 public             | assets                      |         65

We have not recently triggered VACUUM manually , as autovacuum is on. We will give it a try.

That is odd. What PostgreSQL version is that? Does a VACUUM on the table solve the problem?

Please don't write that in comments. [edit] the question and add all the information there.

i see pg_statistic table has lot of dead table,is it because of this planning takes time with a new session?

The current point release of Postgres 14 is 14.12. Postgres 14.4 is hopelessly outdated. You are missing out on two years of security updates and bugfixes. "We recommend that users always run the current minor release associated with their major version." May or may not be related to the issue at hand.

1.6M dead tuples in pg_statistic is way beyond normal. If you are at liberty to do so:
VACUUM FULL pg_catalog.pg_statistic;

Else, at least plain VACUUM.
I wonder how you got there. Looks like very aggressive settings for ANALYZE (which writes to that table), but extremely lax settings for VACUUM (at least for the system table pg_statistic) - or some locking issue that prevented VACUUM.
Repeated invocations get faster planning time, that points to a caching effect. Rows in pg_statistic are comparatively big. I measured an avg of 600 bytes per row in my test DB. Your mileage may vary, especially in case of an increased statistics target (?). Your shared_buffers setting of 1.5 GB should still be enough to cache the table, but we don't know how much cache memory is needed for other stuff. And cache needs to be populated first, which may be what causes the excessive planning time. That, in turn, points to a lack of RAM or very low activity in your DB, so it got evicted from cache earlier. Getting rid of the bloat will help across the board.
Either way, also upgrade to a current version of Postgres, as commented.

Yes, i believe pg_statistic table was the culprit.
some replication slots were in false state, after deleting the non required replication slots, i see autovaccum would have deleted all the millions of dead tuple and brought down the number of dead tuple in pg_statistic table to 760 and now the planning is working as expected .
thanks alot for the help.....
